# Password requirement for all files with a specified extension

Tags: files, security, authentication

I'd like to be able to modify my OS so that that when I go to open any file that has the extension `.zzzz` (an arbitrary extension that I created a few files with, example: `randomText.zzzz`), I would be required to enter a password to open the file -- either the user password or a new password defined within my code.

How would I go about this?

Comment: In addition to the other challenges with what you are trying to achieve, bear in mind that the unique handle to a file is its inode, not the name. Several names (even in different directories) can refer to the same file.

Comment: What about defining a new user with a new password, preventing that user from logging in, assigning all `.zzzz` files to this user, and requiring a `sudo` to run applications that access this file?

Comment: What @JohanMyréen points out is essentially that what you want to do doesn't really make sense in Linux. There are already ways in Linux to protect files. You could give them a special owner and permissions as dirkt suggests or you could encrypt them with a password/key. I'm sure there are other ways as well - none of which would depend on the name of the file which is more of an attribute than a unique identifier.

Comment: Historical interest - on the TRS-80 you could save a file with an 8.3 filename but the extension wouldn't show in a file listing, just the part before the `.`, so in effect the extension was the password.

Comment: This doesn't sound much different from just simply encrypting the files.